# Unity with prime31 Social Networking Plugin Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, prime31

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details. 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe package 
--auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I 
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-14\android.jar"
-F bin/resources.ap_ extra-packages com.facebook.android:com.facebook.android -S            
"C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res" -S
"C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Facebook-Plugin-Library\res"

stderr{
C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-ldpi\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\drawable-xhdpi\com_facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:20: error: Attribute "show_pictures" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:21: error: Attribute "extra_fields" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:22: error: Attribute "show_title_bar" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:23: error: Attribute "title_text" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:24: error: Attribute "done_button_text" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:25: error: Attribute "title_bar_background" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:26: error: Attribute "done_button_background" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:29: error: Attribute "multi_select" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:32: error: Attribute "radius_in_meters" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:33: error: Attribute "results_limit" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:34: error: Attribute "search_text" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:35: error: Attribute "show_search_box" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:38: error: Attribute "confirm_logout" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:39: error: Attribute "fetch_user_info" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:40: error: Attribute "login_text" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:41: error: Attribute "logout_text" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:44: error: Attribute "preset_size" has already been defined

C:\Users\billy\Documents\testFB2\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\attrs.xml:50: error: Attribute "is_cropped" has already been defined

]
```

i am using unity with the prime31 of Social Networking Plugin of android in a totally new project

i just want to try the sample scene in my device but this keep coming when i try to run the scene

Anyone have idea how can i fix this bug??

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just added Stan's assets into our project and it's doing the same exact thing.

Comment: I find out that it is caused by wrong version of java
i installed x64 but it seems it require x86

Comment: Thanks, not sure what our issue was. I had to remove the Facebook SDK and reimport it. Seems to be OK now. But I'm now having problems with Stan's asset and Chartboost rewarded video. Fun times. Fun times.